# How to ask about someone's opinion regarding the future?

Tags: grammar, translation, tense, future

I have a question. I wanna ask:

> "Do You think in the near future/from now on more people will be learning Japanese?".

What is the best way to ask that? I have come up with two ideas:

1. 近い将来は、日本語を勉強している人が増えているだろう/増えると思いますか。
2. これから、日本語を勉強している人が増えていくと思いますか。

Does any of these sound natural?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are great. (I tried to say something more useful, but there is not much else to say, really.)